# Can we update the index document in a AfterSaveCallback event callback

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Can we update the index document in a AfterSaveCallback event callback?
I would like to set an attribute in the document which was just saved and update the newly calculated attribute. Is it possible or this is not safe

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/event/AfterSaveCallback.html

Comment: you can update the document that was saved. If you want to have the change to you do to the entity to be persisted in Elasticsearch, you need to do a new save with the modified document

Comment: Are you saying you can or you cannot or shouldn't

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to update, and if it should be reflected in ES as well. You can change the entity in AftterSaveCallback, but I do no know if this is what you want.

Comment: Yes I want to change an document attribute and save on the AfterSave callback